# Pybind11 and shared libraries

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-libraries, pybind11, python-bindings

I am just starting out with Pybind11 for python bindings with C++ code. Using CMake, the C++ files having functionalities to be imported in python are compiled to a .so(shared library) file in Linux. My question is that after compilation do the .so file need the C++ compiler to be present in the system for my python program to use those functions? For e.g, if I just transferred the .so file to another Linux system with C++ installed and tried to import in a  python file, will it work?

Comment: No. The dynamic linker (ld.so) is responsible for loading libraries as needed. A C++ compiler is only one way  to *generate* these libraries.

Comment: But my question was whether that linker is depended on C++ installation?

Comment: It is not. The dynamic loader is an integral part of the operating system and has nothing to do with a C++ compiler.